# Where are the supported languages in restructuredText code directive documented?

Tags: documentation, restructuredtext

Probably I just can't find the magic words for google, but I just can find the documentation on how to use the `code` directive in restructuredText with the supported languages.

The supported languages can be found here: http://pygments.org/languages/ but I need to know what each [language] translates into in the following code snippet:

```
.. code:: [language]

 {code here}
```

For instance

```
.. code:: bat

 {code here}
```

seems to be `windows batch files`.

Where is this documented?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know any place where this is documented, however looking at the docutils [code](http://docutils.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/docutils/trunk/docutils/docutils/utils/code_analyzer.py?revision=7515&view=markup) shows that docutils uses `pygments.lexers.get_lexer_by_name()` to find the right lexer.

This function takes the **short names** of the lexers given in [pygments lexers](http://pygments.org/docs/lexers/).